# websockets & VPN

Tags: javascript, vpn, websocket

I understand that websocket is still being worked on. Now, I don't know if what I'm considering is even technically possible but I'm just bouncing off ideas.

What I'm thinking of is a client less SSL VPN using websockets. Is it possible to create a websocket & redirect all the traffic from the browser (on that particular site/domain) through this socket. So lets us say you go to a site http://example.com & this site will set up a websocket back to it's server. Now can we in any way capture all the traffic going from that browser tab & push it through that websocket tunnel (wss://). This way you can have a client less SSL VPN solution.

Now, the biggest problem I can see is how do you actually grab all the traffic going from that browser tab or window. I don't think javascript has or will have enough privileges or even capabilities to do that. Any thoughts?

Comment: JavaScript definitely can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could present your own browser UI (URL bar + rendering area), push out HTTP requests over your tunnel and parse & present the returned HTML in the rendering area. But you are correct, you aren't going to be able to capture all browser traffic in javascript without somehow escalating privileges (for example, as a Firefox extension).

Answer (score 0):

A web proxy is really what you are describing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server
All browsers have support for HTTP proxy server settings. If the proxy encapsulated the data with SSL and sent it on to another proxy within the firewall (I assume that's why you mention VPN) then I think you have what you are asking. I don't think WebSockets really has any relevance here. You could use it, but it would just be harder.

Comment: Agreed. This is largely what the SPDY protocol does. (http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper)

Answer (score 0):

Websockets are used to fool DPI in the failed states where whole protocols can be blocked. There are more and more services like that. They're masking as normal HTTPS servers so provider sees just a normal WSS connection to the website. It can also host some random content (recipes?, cats?) to pose as neutral website, and authorize account owners silently to connect on javascript/websocket level